# Does an ASP.net WebForms page keep hold of a database connection?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, connection-pooling

I have a website that under load was showing the db connection pool was exhausted. Also I was receiving timeouts from SQL Server connection attempts.

The site has webpages that do multiple database requests - where the requests are not all in a single db transaction. So what I'm wondering is why doesn't the resultant db data have holes in it if db connections were hard to come by? e.g. if a page does request A and then request B, why don't some of the Bs not happen? There's nothing to suggest that has happened though.

If a web page manages to grab a db connection from the pool, does it get to hang on to it for the duration of its request, even if it repeatably calls open and close on it?

Comment: Reading [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling) is handy for this. You'll have a much better base understanding of connection pooling. Have you reviewed that yet?

Comment: I'll take a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are several cases i can think of.

one case is users in code NOT closing or disposing of their connections.

So, all connection code should be in a "using" block, so the object is disposed of correctly.

eg you might have this:

```
    Dim rstData As New DataTable
    Dim con as SqlCoonnection
    con = New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST3)
    Dim cmdSQL as SqlCommand
    cmdSQL = SqlCommand(strSQL, con)
    cmdSQL.Connection.Open()
    rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
```

So, in above, we execute some command to pull data from SQL server.

But, we don't toss out + dispose of the objects in above.

So, you could write the above this way:

```
    Dim rstData As New DataTable
    Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST3))
        cmdSQL.Connection.Open()
        rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
    End Using

    Return rstData
```

Now in above I have a using for the "sql command" object. And I did NOT create a sepeate connection object. However, if I had created a connection object (like first example), then yes, I would have suggested a using block.

You can however, if you taking a quick code re-view do this:

```
    Dim rstData As New DataTable
    Dim con as SqlCoonnection
    con = New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST3)
    Dim cmdSQL as SqlCommand
    cmdSQL = SqlCommand(strSQL, con)
    cmdSQL.Connection.Open()
    rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)

    cmdSQL.Dispose
    con.Dispose
```